# Where are wafs include stored

Tags: waf

It is possible to give `bld.program` in waf additional include directories with using the keyword argument `includes=` in `bld.program`.

```
def build(bld):
        bld.program(source='main.c', target='app', includes='.')
```

Now I need to get this `includes=` information in a feature. I tried it like this:

```
class _includes(Task.Task):
    before = ['apply_link']

    def run(self):
        print(self.generator.bld.env.INCLUDES)


@TaskGen.feature('include_feature')
@TaskGen.before('apply_link')
def add_include_feature(self):
    self.create_task('_includes')
```

But this only returns the includes that were set during `waf configure`. But I need to get also the additional includes from the keyword argument `includes=`.

How do I get them in the task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is very simple, the information ins stored in `includes`:

```py
class _includes(Task.Task):
    before = ['apply_link']

    def run(self):
        print(self.generator.bld.env.INCLUDES)
        print(self.generator.bld.env.includes)


@TaskGen.feature('include_feature')
@TaskGen.before('apply_link')
def add_include_feature(self):
    self.create_task('_includes')
```